# How do I write example other than String type on quarkus-smallrye-openapi?

Tags: quarkus

I'm using quarkus-smallrye-openapi.
when I wrote the following code.

```
class User {
  @Schema(type = SchemaType.INTEGER, example = "1000")
  private long id;
  ...
}
```

The following schema is generated.

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          format: int64
          type: integer
          example: "1000"
```

The id property's type is integer but example is string.
How do I write an integer and more other types(array, boolean, etc...) example?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's the way smallrye-open-api works. It's nothing to do with Quarkus itself.
I've debugged the way it parses values([here](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/blob/143d798943cdf3319790eed1e68d327d64728484/core/src/main/java/io/smallrye/openapi/runtime/io/schema/SchemaFactory.java#L196)), and even though example object in Schema has Object type, it reads a String value from annotation
 [image]
I filed [an issue to their repo](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/issues/300). If it'll be resolved I'll leave a comment here

---

Update: My pr for this feature was merged, so in the near future, this issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I hope it to be fixed.

Comment: @KeisukeMiyaushiro Just got the answer from both Eclipse and Smallrye team, I'll do a fix for this issue, I'll notify you once again after pr will be merged :)

Comment: @KeisukeMiyaushiro my PR was just merged, might be included in Quarkus 1.5.0